# I cannot solve this assertion error that occurs in my project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I made this cocos2d game and as I was developing it, this assertion error came across randomly in the game. I have spent several weeks trying to solve this, but I have not succeeded yet. The error is

```
Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:z:tag:],  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'nil'
```

Because I have several addChilds, I cannot find which one it is, and to make matters worse, this assertion error occurs very randomly during the run-through at different times. Also, in xcode, when the assertion error happens, it shows me some binary, so I do not know where this error occurs in my actual code. I have also tried using NSZombies, but for some reason it does not work, and it gives me an NSZombie exception. I will happily give my project to anyone who wishes to help me solve this, as it it hard to understand with just me describing it on here.

Comment: why don't you set a breakpoint at each addChild call in your HelloWorldLayer class and step through them to see where your program is crashing at.

Comment: well the problem is that each addChild works for a period of time before the crash, and it happens randomly about 5 - 10 minutes into the game. When I add breakpoints, the project just stops the first time addChild is called, and that is not what I want.

Comment: Also, does anyone know how to to make it so that it shows the error in your actual code instead of binary?

Comment: @Alexyuiop you can edit the breakpoint, and add a condition so that it only breaks when (child == nil). See Xcode 4 User Guide, Edit Breakpoints: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW19

Comment: @Alexyuiop by "binary" I think you mean the machine code. Perhaps "Product -> Debug Workflow -> Show Disassembly when Debugging" is on. If not, you may simply need to select a different entry in the call stack, see my comment to Lukman's answer.

Comment: the question may be localized, but the answers sometimes (as in this case) provide practical guidance that are broad in their use and usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see error message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" when running app in Xcode, you should set a breakpoint on all exceptions in order to find out which line thrown that exception as follows:

[image]

Source: http://www.learningipadprogramming.com/2011/12/10/breakpoint-on-all-exceptions/

Comment: for some reason now, the "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" is gone and now it just says the assertion error message. Also when I do this exception breakpoint, how do you fin out which line the error is on?

Comment: Xcode should jump to the line where the exception occured. If not, perhaps restarting Xcode will fix this. Then check the call stack, that's the tab to the left of the Breakpoint Navigator pane (in the image above, the upper arrow points to the Breakpoint Navigator button, just click the one left to it).